# Do I need to return error: null in JSON response?

Tags: api-design, json

When designing a RESTful API that uses JSON to respond to requests, I usually return an object like this when an error happens:

```
{
  "error": "Something bad happened",
  "error_code": "XXX"
}
```

Do I need to have a `"error": ""` or `"error": null` in my object when there is no error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the response is a success, don't include `error` in your response. Example:

```
GET /product/15406/

200 OK
{
    "id": 15406,
    "name": "A cookie with pieces of chocolate",
    "price": 1.45,
    "is-available": true
}
```

On the other hand, an error would look like:

```
GET /product/nan/

403 Forbidden
{
    "error": 5020,
    "error-message": "The specified product identifier cannot be converted to a number."
}
```

Notes:

- Do change the HTTP status code on error. Returning 200 OK when something got wrong is silly.
- Don't include error fields in the success response. Why would you? You aren't including `price` or `is-available` in the erroneous response, are you?
- Do use strings for text and numbers for numbers. Your `"error_code": "XXX"` looks like you are putting a number as an error code, but passing it as a string. If it's a number, it should remain a number in the response. Note that using strings as error codes may be a good solution: error 5020 is not extremely explicit; error "InvalidProductIdentifier" is.

Comment: The "403 Forbidden" status looks somewhat weird, but HTTP does not have status for invalid parameter, so you can only use "403 Forbidden" or "404 Not Found".

Comment: @JanHudec: actually the 403 here is wrong. For bad parameters you should use *"400 Bad Request"*.

Comment: @vartec: I understand "Bad Request" as not being correct HTTP or having invalid HTTP headers, which is not the case here. So I think  either 404 (because it does not point to valid resource, whether because the format is wrong or because the particular id does not exist being secondary) or 403 (the server states it refuses to talk to about URL not matching the specified format).

Comment: @vartec: from what I've seen, APIs tend to use 403 in many cases (including wrong parameters). IMO, it doesn't really matter which one among 400, 403 or 404 is used, as long as the API is consistent.

Comment: @JanHudec: 400 is any bad request, doesn't matter if it's malformed HTTP, a syntax error or just request that doesn't pass the validation. Using 400 in this case is for example the standard way as described in the ["RESTful Web Services" book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260.do)